# From an integral theorem, derive (one of Green’s Identities)

Tags: vector-analysis

> From an integral theorem, derive (one of Green’s Identities):
>   $$\int_V(\psi \nabla ^2 \phi−\phi \nabla ^2 \psi) dV=\int_{\partial
> V}(\psi \frac {\partial \phi}{\partial n}−\phi \frac{\partial
> \psi}{\partial n})dS$$

Almost certainly the integral theorem to use is the divergence theorem. 
$\int_V \nabla \cdot {\bf F} dV=\int_{\partial V} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}$. $d{\bf S}={\bf n}dS$, but I'm struggling here with what $\bf n$ is, I get that it's the outwards normal, but specifically what it is here is what I'm struggling with.

Apologies if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Observe, we have the identity
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\left(\psi\nabla\phi-\phi\nabla\psi\right) = \psi\nabla^2\phi-\phi\nabla^2\psi.
\end{align}
Then using Gauss's Theorem, we obtain the identity
\begin{align}
\int_V \nabla\cdot\left(\psi\nabla\phi-\phi\nabla\psi\right)\ dV =& \int_{\partial V}  (\psi\nabla\phi-\phi\nabla\psi)\cdot\mathbf{n}\ dS\\
=& \int_{\partial V} \psi\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n} -\phi\nabla\psi\cdot\mathbf{n}\ dS=\int_{\partial V} \psi\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}- \phi \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial n}\ dS.
\end{align}

Comment: $\mathbf{n}$ is the vector that's perpendicular to your surface $\partial V$.

Comment: Looks like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#/media/File:Divergence_theorem.svg.

Comment: Sorry, that was my terrible wording. What I meant was write out $\bf n$ like a vector $(n_1,n_2,...,n_m)$

Comment: Well, that depends on $\partial V$. If $\partial V$ is the sphere centered at the origin, then $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{x}/|| \mathbf{x}||$ for any $\mathbf{x}$ vector.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, so how did you know $\psi \nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf n=\psi \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}$? Thanks so far

Comment: That's the definition.

Comment: I really appreciate everything so far, but maybe I'm being an idiot, but I can't see how this is equivalent to the previous definitions on $\bf n$, could I possibly ask further for an explanation of this? Thanks a lot either way